# Freya font rendering problem after last update

Tags: release-freya, graphics

I have EOS freya installed since 2015 with no issues. Yesterday I did my last update. After I logged in I got this strange message, see the screenshot attached below

I reinstalled graphic drivers and the issue disappeared, although now the font rendering is not as good as before. There is a lot blurring around fonts, and pdf that looked great before now are so badly rendered, unless I zoom a lot. It's like when you look at a picture with low dpi.

What should I check/do?

Regards
Pietro

[image]